# Passing variable to npm app inside a container

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, kubernetes

I've build a npm react-app that connects to a REST-backend using a given url.
To run the app on kubernetes, I've distributed the app and put it into an nginx container.
The app starts nicely, but I want to make the backend url configurable without having to rebuild the container image every time.
I don't know how to do that or where to search for, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several methods to achieve your objective

- [Use environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/)

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
     name: pod-name
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: envar-demo-container
        image: my_image:my_version
        env:
         - name: BACKEND_URL
           value: "http://my_backend_url"
```

- [Using a configmap as a config file for your service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/)
- If the service is external, you can use a fixed name and register as a local kubernetes service: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-mapping-external-services

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Ingress.  If the react app and the rest backend are both hosted on kubernetes, I recommend using a relative path for the REST backend http://myurl for app, http://myurl/service for the backend.  Then use ingress to map the /service path to the REST service.  Your react app just points to /service and doesn't care about url you are hosting on.